# List Post Categories Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to list my all of the categories of the Wordpress posts in an input like so:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="something" id="[category-name]" value="[category-name] + ([amount of posts that have this category])" />
```

Anyone who can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)...as long as you're a bit flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into formatting the output of `get_categories()`:

```
$catlist = get_categories();
foreach ($cat in $catlist) {
    $tag = '<input type="checkbox" class="something" id="';
    $tag .= $cat->name;
    $tag .= '" value="';
    $tag .= $cat->name;
    $tag .= ' + (';
    $tag .= $cat->count;
    $tag .= ')" />';
    echo $tag;
 }
```

From the WP Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Return_values